# xaml accessing Grid cause process hang

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, dispatcher

I am developing windows phone 8.1 app, and I have this issue:

I am trying to call `Children.RemoveAt(0)` with this function:

```
 public void ReleaseMediaElement()
{
    if (_gridToInjectMediaElement != null && _gridToInjectMediaElement.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        bool access = Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess;
        if (access)
        {
            _gridToInjectMediaElement.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            //Or : _gridToInjectMediaElement.Children.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                _gridToInjectMediaElement.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            }).AsTask().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

However, my process hangs from time to time as I am getting `Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess == true`.

I am calling this function sometimes from UI and sometimes from Worker thread - that's why I am trying to use the dispatcher.

The hang isn't consistently...

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: Is the Children collection thread-safe? It seems to me there is nothing to prevent a situation in which two threads check for Count>0 and then both go and try to remove the item for which one of them will see that there is actually nothing left to remove... a race condition that is.

Comment: The Children collection isn't safe, it's the standard ItemsCollection of the Grid control

Comment: There is no rise condition since this function isn't accessible by two different threads simultaneously, it is accessed by one thread each time. However, the hang happens event after I've surrounded the code with double checked locking